# Having trouble installing pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So... I'm using Python 2.7.5, and I'm attempting to install pygame. I downloaded this: pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi 3.1MB

from [here](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) and ran the program, which then created pygame in the python folder, and from what I can tell all of the associated files are there. However, when I tried to run the sample program from [this tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html), it threw the following error message:L

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Bouncing ball", line 1, in <module>
    import sys, pygame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Does anyone know what the issue is, and what I can do to correct it? I am running a 64 bit Windows 7 computer, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are using 64 bit python and you installed 32 bit pygame you will need to find a win64 version ... or what ever the 64 bit version is... or install the 32 bit python and use that (I use 32 bit python on my 64 bit machine)

Comment: That worked, thank you. I think I was confused by the "windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.", but I did install the 64bit Python, so that makes sense. I found the 64bit here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: You should accept that answer to show that this question has been resolved.